# Terraform aws_alb_listener_rule with host AND path conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

AWS ALB [supports](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) rules based on matching both host and path conditions in the same rule.

> You can also create rules that combine host-based routing and path-based routing.

I've checked the console and the UI does indeed allow for selecting host and path conditions in the same rule.

Terraform [aws_alb_listener_rule](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/alb_listener_rule.html) seems to support host OR path conditions.

> Must be **one** of path-pattern for path based routing or host-header for host based routing.

Emphasis mine

Is there a way to Terraform an ALB rule that only triggers when both the request hostname and path match some criteria?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify two conditions, which results in an AND of the two conditions:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "host_header_rule" {
  condition {
    field  = "host-header"
    values = ["some.host.name"]
  }
  condition {
    field  = "path-pattern"
    values = ["/some-path/*"]
  }
  # etc.
}
```

Comment: Such an obvious thing *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

```
resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "listener_path_based_test" {
    listener_arn = "${aws_alb_listener.listener_prod_https_internal_test.arn}"
    action {    
      type             = "forward"    
      target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.tg_alb_prod_8080_internal_test.arn}"
    }   
    condition {    
     field  = "path-pattern"      
     values = ["/some-path/*"]}}
```